# Word for someone who says yes, then no, then yes

Tags: word-choice, word-request

Facing a situation that needs a decision, a person says **yes** then in a minute later changes it to **no**, but he/she does it several times and does not have a real decision eventually.

What is the single word for it? If I translate directly from my native language, it comes to "unreliable". But, I don't quite agree with it, because it's a typical characteristic of people who hardly decides.

How about [wishy washy](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wishy+washy)?

Comment: That person is *Confused*

Comment: I think _mother_ would also be a good word.

Comment: I like wishy washy, myself.

Comment: [Richard II](https://youtu.be/6UHaMJEE0MM?t=3m43s)

Comment: A bilingual dictionary gives *waver* as a first choice (along with *waverer*, *waveringly*). I think it's apt.

Comment: "Vicky Pollard"

Comment: Agree with @ToddWilcox. Wishy washy is a great fit for informal conversation.

Comment: wishy-washy for the win

Comment: It's not English, so maybe not welcome here, but it but widely used. As a UK native speaker here, my first thought was "volte face" http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/volte-face Although, admittedly, that only refers to changing once, not repeatedly (in which case I would go for vacillating. "Volte face" might be useful to know, though. It can also be rendered in English as "Mr. X did a complete about face"

Answer (score 31):

This person is a [vacillator](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/vacillate). ​

Comment: Is this an especially common term? I wouldn't expect to hear it in everyday conversation. It seems more suited to a more formal or *extremely* polite context.

Comment: @jpmc26 -- "Vacillate", "vacillating" and "vacillated" are reasonably common, in contexts where the audience is educated.  These words describe exactly what the original poster is asking about.    I do not know any other single-word terms that have this specific meaning.  Thesaurus.com [suggests](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/vacillate) "alternate", but "alternate" is a much more general term.  The most common meaning of "alternator" is a mechanical-electrical device to convert direct current into alternating current.

Comment: I'm a native speaker who enjoys obscure words, and I had never heard this before. (I'm familiar with the verb "to vacillate", but I'd never heard it as a noun before.) Just a note to the OP: if you use this word in conversation, be prepared to be explain what it means.

Comment: I was going to suggest "dither" or "vacillate" for the verbs and "ambivalent" for the adjective form just off the top of my head. It's not "basic English" but it is in common use in my circles.

Comment: Adam tends to oscillate between yes and no.  He is an oscillator.

Answer (score 26):

**ditherer**   noun  
One who dithers; one who is unable to decide; a procrastinator. 
         
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ditherer

**dither**    verb   
To be uncertain or unable to make a decision about doing something. 
      noun  
The state of being undecided. 
         
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dither

(One technological use of the word *dithering* is to add fuzz
on both sides of an edge in a computer image.)

Comment: It sounds like the problem in the OP's example isn't with making a decision, but rather with sticking with one.

Comment: The meaning of *dithering* in technological context is a little different, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither.

Comment: Indeed, @HannoBinder, *dithering* has broader technological usage than my example. Thank you for the link, my wording now begins "*One* technological use ... ." This example comes from personal experience.

Comment: [Dither](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/dither) as I (a native speaker) understand it, means to be unable to make a decision. The OP seems to be asking a about someone who makes a decision, then changes it, then changes it again, which imho does not match *dither*.

Answer (score 21):

Some single word adjectives for someone who is constantly **changing their mind**:

> **indecisive
>
>   flip-flop
>
>   tempermental**

**Indecisive** has the meaning of **not being able to make a decision**
**Flip-flop** describes an action of **one side to the other side**
**Tempermental** describes someone who **runs hot and cold**

All of these words describe a **to-ing and fro-ing**, **back and forth**

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Thanks for the feedback, I thought I had put those in originally. Answer has been edited

Comment: *Temperamental* might not be the best choice from this list because it is commonly used in regards to a person's "emotional temperament" - quickly becoming "hot", also known as "angry", rather than just changing their mind about something. If someone were described as temperamental I would think that meant they become very angry at a moment's notice - probably regarding certain topics.

Answer (score 20):

[**waffler**](https://www.wordnik.com/words/waffler)

This one is a noun. I'm surprised it hasn't already been taken. :)

Comment: I always thought of a **waffler** as one who **can not make up their mind**  *(to begin with)* as opposed to **making a decision then changing it**. Good word though

Comment: @Peter I thought about that too. But I looked it up a bit and I think the usage can cover a change of mind after the decision as well.

Comment: "He **waffled** about whether he wanted a **waffle**", but I can see "He chose a **waffle**, and then **waffled**", which sounds like he ate the **waffle** when in fact he may have ate the **waffle** or may not have eaten the **waffle** (how many times can one mention **waffle** in a comment, oh, there's another one...)

Comment: @Peter If you told me someone was a waffler I'd think you meant they talked almost continuously without saying anything important. I hadn't heard this meaning before.

Comment: @CJDennis **Waffle** has both the meaning of being **evasive** and **incessant**, the latter is to **waffle on** *a subject* as opposed to **waffle on** *a decision*

Comment: [To waffle has different meanings in UK and US English](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/waffle): "**British** - Speak or write at length in a vague or trivial manner: *he waffled on about his problems*. **North American** - Fail to make up one’s mind:
*Joseph had been waffling over where to go*"

Comment: @user568458 That's the difference between **waffle** and **waffle on** (can't seem to edit the emphasis in my comment above for some reason), from my experience the latter is used in both AmE and BrE, and then there are the **Belgians**...

Answer (score 6):

There could be more than one word but you can use *'dilemma'*. So, if a person cannot decide things...

> S/he is *always* in *[dilemma](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dilemma)*.

Another option is...

> The person is *[indecisive](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/INDECISIVE)*.

Comment: Indecisive, yes; dilemma, not so much. A dilemma is a situation that *would normally give anyone trouble with the decision*, while this is someone who acts as though faced with a dilemma even for decisions that are no such thing.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I think dilemma could go with it; irrespective of the intelligence of a person, ultimately, there's no decision made. First saying 'yes' and then saying 'no' and then finally, no decision. If this happens every time, I'd certainly call him/her a person who is always in dilemma (i.e. doesn't know what to decide/choose). But yes, *'indecisive'* is more accurate.

Comment: I would upvote this for indecisive but I would downvote it for dilemma so you end up with nothing ....

Comment: "Dilemma" may apply in such a case, but not like that. Someone who faces a dilemma may well freeze or go back and fourth, but that's not implied or denoted by the term. "In dilemma" sounds grammatically incorrect to me, too, but I'm not going to argue that point.

Comment: *in dilemma* incorrect? [Not so](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/dehradun/Congress-in-dilemma-over-allies-for-2017-polls-in-Uttarakhand/articleshow/50417920.cms) @TheNate

Comment: In formal US English, "in a dilemma" is preferred. Dropping the article "a" (or "the") does sound like something Brit.E. would allow, hence my wording.

Answer (score 6):

Most of the answers here work (though many are a bit judgmental), but the correct answer will depend on the speaker's mental state or motivations.

For example, in addition to the possibilities already mentioned, the person might simply be *conflicted* (as, famously, [Shakespeare's Richard II](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6UHaMJEE0MM&feature=youtu.be&t=3m43s)).

Answer (score 4):

"Irresolute" could fit in well.

Comment: On these lines: "uncertain" or "unconvinced" could serve, too, and probably sound more casual. "Resolute" sounds old fashioned to me. That's fine, mind, but may not be the goal.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well.

Answer (score 3):

You may also use "fickle minded"

Comment: I'd thought of this too. +1 it is a good option.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well.

Comment: *Fickle* itself fits the bill.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with ["capricious"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/capricious).

Often, it goes together in the expression "arbitrary and capricious", which sounds like it might fit, too.

Answer (score 2):

"Hesitant", was the first thing that popped into my mind, although it might apply more to a person who does not decide at all.

Answer (score 2):

**hesitant**, **temperamental**, **indecisive**, **irresolute**, **tentative**.

Any of those words should work appropriately for *describing* such a person.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well.

Answer (score 1):

If the person doesn't commit strongly to either yes or no (rather than e.g. expressing a strong opinion one way, then changing their mind to a strong opinion the opposite way) they could be described as an [**equivocator**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Equivocator):

> a respondent who avoids giving a clear direct answer

Comment: Equivocation is using words in more than one sense, not really  changing one's mind. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/equivocate and http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/equivocate